# Read sensor data in node red

Tags: sensor

I need some help in building a salt water station that will measure temperature, electrical conductivity and dissolved oxygen. These three sensors will be hooked up on a tentacle t3 and on a raspberry pi 4b. I have scripts to read the data but i dont know how to use them in node red. Any help would be appreciate. Im using the atlas scientific sample script but when i run it i get a list with commands and responses, o type poll for example and i get the temperature data. What should i change in that script in order to just run it and get the data without the need of giving a command?

Comment: Normally you call a script using the exec node in node-red and the message payload is the standard out output from the program.  Without knowing what you script does the only thought I have is to pipe the input via standard in if you cannot change the code. `echo abc | pgm` where 'abc' is what you would type and pgm is your program.

Comment: you are asking for suggestions to make changes in an unknown script